# Dual computer one monitor vga/dvi

Tags: display, vga, dvi

I have a HP desktop and an Acer laptop. The laptop can do VGA or DVI and the desktop can only do VGA. The hp monitor has HDMI, VGA,and DVI support all on different ports on the back.

I have the desktop connected through VGA and the laptop through DVI. The monitor allows transition between the connections but it always recognizes the desktop first and then won't let me change over to the laptop through DVI. Any help?

Comment: The information provided gives no information on the monitor which would be the device that handles this transition. I would suggest referring to the manufacture as this will be a very specific issue to this make and model of monitor - It will be unlikely to find someone here who has the exact same make and model

Answer (score 1):

The HP monitor is behaving as expecting. Even though it has multiple video inputs, you can only select one at a time. You might be able to switch over to the DVI from VGA, if you unplug the VGA connection and perform an auto-select on the monitor. That should detect the DVI. The downside is that you have to constantly switch the inputs back and forth.

**You want to know the better solution? It is called a KVM switch.**

Comment: A workaround rather than an answer to the question... just connect the Monitor to the Laptop, and Remote Desktop to the PC, and leave the remote desktop as Full Screen on the monitor (either the monitor, or the laptop monitor) therefore you don't have the issue of moving the connection around and can see both screen on laptop, and on PC.